# Only return in if statement under recursive function

Tags: python

I am expecting the result to be 10 but it returns None, any idea why?

```py
def function(index):
    if index==9:
        print(index)
        return 10
    else:
        print(index)
        index=index+1
        function(index)
print(function(6))
``
```

Comment: There's missing return in `function(index)`

Comment: Because you are not returning in the `else`... After the recursive call returns, it does not return... change to `return function(index)`

Comment: put return function(index) under else solves problem, thank you!